# mysql null to 0

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT * from book;
```

how to convert NULL result to 0 from the sql ?

Answer (score 17):

You're looking for the COALESCE keyword:

```
SELECT COALESCE(fieldName, 0) FROM book
```

Comment: can change fieldname to ALL ?i want to select all

Comment: @nuclearmaker: No, you have to do that for all relevant columns. Something like `SELECT COALESCE(field1, 0), COALESCE(field2, 0) FROM book;`

Comment: You should never use `*` in practice, you should always list the fields you want to get.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT IFNULL(pages, 0) FROM book;
```

if `pages` was the name of your column.

Comment: Probably not incredibly important in most cases, but seems worth noting that Coalesce is part of the SQL Standard and IfNull is not.  If portability is a concern, Coalesce is the way to go

Comment: I like ifnull.  coalesce sounds too pretentious.